# Kubernetes Job Cleanup

Tags: kubernetes, jobs

From what I understand the Job object is supposed to reap pods after a certain amount of time.
But on my GKE cluster (Kubernetes 1.1.8) it seems that "kubectl get pods -a" can list pods from days ago.

All were created using the Jobs API.

I did notice that after delete the job with
    kubectl delete jobs
The pods were deleted too.

My main concern here is that I am going to run thousands and tens of thousands of pods on the cluster in batch jobs, and don't want to overload the internal backlog system.

Answer (score 64):

It looks like starting with Kubernetes 1.6 (and the v2alpha1 api version), if you're using cronjobs to create the jobs (that, in turn, create your pods), you'll be able to [limit](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/) how many old jobs are kept.  Just add the following to your job spec:

```
successfulJobsHistoryLimit: X
failedJobsHistoryLimit: Y
```

Where X and Y are the limits of how many previously run jobs the system should keep around (it keeps jobs around indefinitely by default [at least on version 1.5.])

Edit **2018-09-29**:

For newer K8S versions, updated links with documentation for this are here:

- [CronJob - Job History Limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#jobs-history-limits)
- [CronJob API Spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#cronjob-v1beta1-batch)

Comment: Small correction at least version 1.6! Make sure that both server and client are at version 1.6 by using `kubectl version`

Comment: You can find the documentation here (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/) as of Aug 21, 18.

Answer (score 17):

It's true that you used to have to delete jobs manually. @puja's answer was correct at the time of writing.

Kubernetes 1.12.0 released a TTL feature (in alpha) where you can set it to automatically clean up jobs a specified number of seconds after completion ([changelog](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.12.md#new-features)). You can set it to zero for immediate cleanup. See the [Jobs docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#ttl-mechanism-for-finished-jobs).

Example from the doc:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi-with-ttl
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl
        command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: Did you test it? I am facing this bug https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/70685

Comment: It should be the preferred solution however still in alpha and needs some extra work like enabling feature gates and restarting apiserver so not always possible at hosted solutions like ELK or DO.

Comment: It's depended on TTL controller which is a feature of v1.21. per https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/ttlafterfinished/

Answer (score 5):

I recently built a kubernetes-operator to do this task.

After deploy it will monitor selected namespace and delete completed jobs/pods if they completed without errors/restarts.

https://github.com/lwolf/kube-cleanup-operator

Answer (score 3):

This is the intended behaviour of Jobs even in Kubernetes 1.3. Both the job and its pods stay in the system until you delete them manually. This is to provide you with a way to see results of the pods (i.e. through logs) that were not transported outside by some mechanism already or check for errors, warnings, or other diagnostic output.

The recommended/[official](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jobs/#job-termination-and-cleanup) way to get rid of the pods is to delete the job as you mentioned above. Using the garbage collector would only delete the pods, but the job itself would still be in the system.

If you don't want to delete the job manually, you could write a little script that is running in your cluster and checks for completed jobs and deletes them. Sadly, Scheduled Jobs are only [coming in 1.4](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/11980) but you could run the script in a normal pod instead.

Answer (score 2):

In kubernetes v1.2, there is a garbage collector for reaping terminated pods with a global threshold `--terminated-pod-gc-threshold=12500` (see the flags in [controller manager](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/8cc91944e0555af82f86cc7f21fb638be60665fd/docs/admin/kube-controller-manager.md). I am not aware of any GC mechanism for terminated pods in v1.1.8. You may want to run a script/pod to periodically clean up the pods/jobs to prevent the master components from being overwhelmed. By the way, there is an open issue to [automatically adjust the GC threshold](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22680).