# How to filter finished jobs in kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubectl, client-go

I'm trying to filter jobs that are complete using golang kubernetes client-go lib by their status.

I've checked [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53412583/268673) explaining how to get the jobs using kubectl, like this:

```
kubectl get job -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.succeeded==1)].metadata.name}'
```

But I don't know how to "turn" that jsonpath output into a filter or list options

If I were searching for pods by their status phase and a label I would do something like this:

```golang
listOptions := metav1.ListOptions{
    LabelSelector: "app.kubernetes.io/name=my-custom-job",
    FieldSelector: "status.phase=Running",
}
result, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("default").List(listOptions)
```

But if I am going to implement the jsonpath `{.items[?(@.status.succeeded==1)].metadata.name}`

This is going to iterate through all jobs and check if the succeeded key under status is equal to one. For all jobs.

**Is there a way to look for those jobs more "memory friendly" or a way to use jsonpaths like that in ListOptions?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, you can filter out, on the server-side, only finished jobs.

```golang
listOptions := metav1.ListOptions{
    FieldSelector: "status.successful=1",
}
result, err := clientset.BatchV1().Jobs("").List(listOptions)
```

*status.successful* field from the job's spec is being directly mapped to *status.succeeded* field from **metav1.ListOptions.FieldSelector**. [More info about that.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.18/pkg/registry/batch/job/strategy.go#L205)

That being said, the list of available options to filter on the server-side is highly restricted. You **can not** filter using arbitrary fields from the spec (e.g. *status.active* or *spec.parallelism*). [Github Issue on that.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/53459)