# How kubernetes can delete automatically the completed jobs?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have problems to delete automatically the completed jobs which were started by a CronJob.
As I read in this QA [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43116061/5843405) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384873/kubernetes-job-cleanup?noredirect=1&lq=1), and in the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#jobs-history-limits), this can be done establishing the job history limit
`.spec.successfulJobsHistoryLimit` and `.spec.failedJobsHistoryLimit`. I have done it, and it is established to 1 for both cases. But my cluster is saving more than 1 completed job, in fact, it is saving more than the default which is 3 successful jobs and 1 for failed jobs.

My current CronJob configuration is

```
 apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
 kind: CronJob
 metadata:
    name: some-name-cron
 spec:
   schedule: "00 05 1/1 * ?"
   successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
   failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
   jobTemplate:
     spec: ...
```

And my versions are:
- Client version: `Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9",`
- Server version: `Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8+",`

So, what I am doing wrong?

I've attached a image with the k8s dashboard.

[image: Dashboard screenshot with the completed Jobs and Pods]

Comment: `00 05 1/1 * ?` what actually you wany?

Comment: And also share your whole CronJob yaml

Comment: @j-sebio Did you find a solution to this? I'm running into the same behavior, cronjob history settings are in the spec, but they apply only to pods, not to jobs I guess...

Comment: @j-sebio I am having the same issue, did you resolve this?

Comment: I think the scenarios is, K8S CronJob created a mediator K8S Job, that creates actual K8S Job from file (Actual K8S job manifest written in configmap and that cm mounted as volume in Cronjob), and in this case setting `successfulJobsHistoryLimit` to 0 in cronJob didn't removed the mediator K8S Job pod even after successful completion?!?!

Answer (score 6):

You can use jobs history limits **successfulJobsHistoryLimit** and **failedJobsHistoryLimit** to set how many completed and failed jobs should be kept.

You can check for more details on it in the Kubernetes docs here:

[Kubernetes - Cronjob: Jobs History Limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#jobs-history-limits)

Comment: I'm using  `successfulJobsHistoryLimit` and` failedJobsHistoryLimit` in the CronJob specification as is shown in the attached code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757277/how-kubernetes-can-delete-automatically-the-completed-jobs but is not working.

Comment: If the limits don't work for you, I recommend you to open an issue directly to [Kubernetes Issues on GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues)

Comment: For some reason, the main documentation linked above stopped listing these parameters. But, you can still find them in the API documentation (present at least in versions 1.10-1.12): https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.12/#cronjob-v1beta1-batch

Comment: I also see the parameters listed here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/#jobs-history-limits